# KryoConverters serializer in python

Tags: python, java, python-3.x, kotlin, kryo

I want to develope this code in python:
`Base64Encoder.encodeUrlSafe(ZipUtil.zlib(KryoConverters.serialize(this), 9))`

i found kotlin code in this repo:
https://github.com/SagerNet/SagerNet/blob/dev/app/src/main/java/io/nekohasekai/sagernet/fmt/UniversalFmt.kt

base64encode and zlib will have no problem.
But i can't find any KryoConverters library.
How can i do that?

Comment: Maybe it's related to [this line](https://github.com/SagerNet/SagerNet/blob/60c9544515fd4d09c217e004b3abedb31a01bd83/app/build.gradle.kts#L64).

Comment: @dan1st yeah. but this library not in python.